# Having trouble with Jquery UI tootips - Images

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a hover tooltip that shows an image instead of text, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tips").tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return '<img src="' + $(this).attr("href") + '" />'
        }
    });
});
```

For this Html

```
<a href="http://materialmix.com/uploads/5e9667aa-3537-4c41-8d01-520447285b76_r.jpg" class="tips">
                                            <img src="http://plastic.jasonscms.com//images/camera.png">
                                        </a>
```

I created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3B9H/

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  It does nothing right now, and does not error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the `items` parameter because you are not using the default `title` attribute. See [tooltip items](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-items).

Now, you'll need to adjust your content function to find the parent anchor:

```
$(".tips").tooltip({
    items: "img",
    content: function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var src = element.parent("a.tips").attr("href");
        console.log(src);
        return '<img src="' + src + '" class="tooltip-img" />'
    }
});

<style>
    .tooltip-img { height: 25px; width: 30px; }
</style>
```

Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3B9H/2/).

Comment: Marking this as correct as it does not require extra markup.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add "title" attribute with some arbitrary value to your element to make tooltip work.

```
<a title="default tooltip" href="http://materialmix.com/uploads/5e9667aa-3537-4c41-8d01-520447285b76_r.jpg" class="tips">
    <img src="http://plastic.jasonscms.com//images/camera.png" />
</a>
```